# OpenLayers 3 - Build GetMap query string for WMS

Tags: openlayers, wms

We have an application with OpenLayers 2. There we are using WMS layers, which make requests to an custom Web service. This Web service creates an image for the current map window.
To achieve that, we use the [getUrl](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.getURL) method, where the bounds are passed and where we build the URL for the request.

For OpenLayers 3 I have not seen that possibility. What is the best way here to solve this?

EDIT:
In ol2, we used the getUrl method of the WMS layer object to build a specific url for each WMS request. Is there an equivalent there for ol3?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you currently have.  When you say a custom web service do you mean you have your own WMS or is it some other sort of service you are calling?

Comment: It is just an ASP.NET Web API Webservice. There we have a service method which recieves (among others) the id of the datasource, the CRS and the extents. With this information, the webservice method renders the image and gives it back.

Comment: To make it (hopefully) clearer: in ol2, we used the getUrl method of the WMS layer object to build a specific url for each WMS request. Is there an equivalent there for ol3?

Comment: No one has an answer?